# In WiX, is it possible to update the status text when executing custom actions?

Tags: wix

When I'm running (multiple) lengthy custom actions, can I update the GUI's status text with some info on the progress?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [Jonathon Rossi's blog post](http://www.jonorossi.com/blog/archive/2008/07/20/wix-progress-text-for-a-custom-action.aspx) - yes, you can! But you'll need to tweak your WiX UI for that:

> If you have a custom action like:
>
> ```
> <CustomAction Id="CA_DevEnv2008Setup"
>               Property="DEVENV2008_EXE_PATH"
>               ExeCommand="/setup" Impersonate="no"
>               Execute="deferred" />
> ```
>
> Then a ProgressText element like the
>   following will set the status text
>   while it is running:
>
> ```
> <UI>
>   <ProgressText Action="CA_DevEnv2008Setup">Configuring Foo... (this may take a few minutes).</ProgressText>
> </UI>
> ```

Comment: It's possible to change it dynamically from c# code inside custom action?